# Prevent user to go next line by pressing softkey enter in autocompletetextview

Tags: android

I am trying to **disable** the key to go ***next line*** so that autocompletetextview works as single line like a search box and after selecting the correct text from list the cursor will be disabled and keyboard will disappear

**Problem 1:** Though I have done this cursor disabling with textview a while back maybe it will work here too but keyboard still remains there until I press back key on mobile.

**Problem 2:** Since I have tried maxLines="1", lines="1" and couple of things more but it is not working as it should be.

**What I want :** User can select only one item from list.

**Code :**

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/list_names"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:minWidth="150dp"
    android:ems="10"
 />
```

**JAVA:**

```
 public void getList(){

    try{
          while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                list.add(scanner.next());
           }
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
 }

 public void populate(){

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    autolist.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

I have also tried to block some keyevent from keyboard action

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode == 66 || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION)) {

        return false;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Still not working.
**Before pressing enter key**
[image: Before pressing enter]

**After pressing enter key** 
[image: After Pressing enter key]

Comment: return true; in if condition of onKey method

Comment: @UsmanRana not working it act as single line since I put this  lines="1" but suppose I enter M then press enter key so it moves to next line but I don't see M when I press back to delete I see that M is being deleted. You get it ? It never blocked enter or done key instead only one line is visible at one time since I have used lines="1" that's why

Answer (score 6):

Add the `android:inputType="text"` property to the `AutoCompleteTextView` to disable the `enter` button to go to next line.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/list_names"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            />
```

Update:
Hide keyboard on pressing Enter/Done in keyboard

```
autolist.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                    Log.e("TAG","Done pressed");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Hide keyboard on selecting the suggestion

```
autolist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                View view = getCurrentFocus();
                if (view != null) {
                    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: worked but which keycode is necessary so that i put that one and remove other

Comment: Ok get it so lines="1" is doing the work but suppose I enter a word and I press enter then list is showing autocomplete for empty box like "67 street AMI, 991-get_lop" like this and yeah i removed that keycode event blocking

Comment: 'android:inputType="text' will  change `enter` button to `next` don't need the `lines=1` incase item are more than 1 lines

Comment: Yeah sadiq but the problem is suppose I type something like "M" and then I press enter then different list appear

Comment: isn't that supposed to be the effect of Autocomplete to suggest you item related to the text you are entering ?

Comment: but it is not suggesting me the entered text see  wait I am adding two images please take a look

Comment: I have added image please take a look before pressing enter is working fine as it should be but after that new suggestion shows up not according to the entered text

Comment: Asif if I leave this one out still I got issue that cursor should be visible only and only when I touch this view else always invisible

Comment: can you post more of your java code? i have tested on my Xperia Z2 running Android 6.0 ! it doesn't have any enter button after that code and there is a `done` button. if i press that nothing happen like you say

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133248/discussion-between-sadiq-md-asif-and-sameerkhan1406).

Comment: Okay I have minsdkVersion 15 and running code on Xolo 5.0

Comment: come to discussion

Answer (score 0):

Use this in XML :
 android:singleLine="true"